# How to take the shortest path with Slick slider dots (infinite mode on)?

Tags: slick.js

I'm using slick slider with infinite mode on and I would like that the dots take the shortest path. Ex : I am on the first slide and I click on the last dot it should go one slide left and not 4 slides right (I have 5 slides).

I tried to change the scrolling direction with negative values for slidesToScroll but it did not work.